# How to make a return from a child function cause a return to the parent function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ash

I have a parent function and child function:

```
parent() {

   child aa1 bb1 cc1
   child aa2 bb2 cc2
   child aa3 bb3 cc3
   child aa4 bb4 cc4

}

child() {
  ....
  if [ some error reason ]; then return 1; fi
  ...
}
```

How to make the `return 1` (of the child) cause a return in the parent and then avoid the execute the remaining child calls?

without adding a check of the returned value after each child call like this

```
parent() {

   child aa1 bb1 cc1
   e=$?; [ "$e" != "0" ] && return $e
   child aa2 bb2 cc2
   e=$?; [ "$e" != "0" ] && return $e
   child aa3 bb3 cc3
   e=$?; [ "$e" != "0" ] && return $e
   child aa4 bb4 cc4
   e=$?; [ "$e" != "0" ] && return $e

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a solution other than `set -e` and `|| return`

It's simple, just use `exit` instead of `return` and the parent should called in a sub-shell:

```
parent() {
   child aa1 bb1 cc1
   child aa2 bb2 cc2
   child aa3 bb3 cc3
   child aa4 bb4 cc4
}

child() {
  ....
  if [ some error reason ]; then exit 1; fi
  ...
}
```

And I call the parent in this way:

```
( parent )
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `|| return` to the end of each call. The value returned by `return` is the return status of the last command executed when not specified. (Thanks kojiro for the reminder).

Or just use `set -e` if `ash` supports that (though that has [some non-obvious limitations](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) about when it fails to work correctly that make some people suggest that you avoid using it). Run `set -e` before your commands and any "simple command" failure will cause the shell to exit immediately but the previous solution is more flexible.

Comment: example of using set -e ?

Comment: Sorry @EtanReisner, But I have to accept my answer since it's the right one now

Answer (score 4):

Add `set -e` in your `parent` function:

```
parent() {
   set -e
   child aa1 bb1 cc1
   child aa2 bb2 cc2
   child aa3 bb3 cc3
   child aa4 bb4 cc4
}
```

Then call it as:

```
( parent )
```

This will run `parent` function in a sub-shell and sub-shell **will be terminated as soon as there is a non-zero exit** status from any of the `chile` function call.

Comment: Etan said in his answer that `the set -e has some non-obvious limitations about when it fails to work correctly that make some people avoid using it`. There is a risk that it doesn't work properly when using set -e? The ash already support set -e